# user not staying logged in after changes to user password and username

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-users

I have made a django view and form to update username and password and it does what it's meant to do, but I have trouble with the user staying logged in after the changes are done:

Here's my view logic:

```
class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    template_name = 'todo_list/userupdate.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("tasks")
    
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        if user is not None:
            login(self.request, user)
        return super(UserUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

As you can see the idea is for the user to be logged in after the changes are made, which doesn't happen. The user is automatically logged out and I don't know why.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change):

> If your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` inherits from `AbstractBaseUser` or implements
> its own `get_session_auth_hash()` method, authenticated sessions will
> include the hash returned by this function. In the `AbstractBaseUser`
> case, this is an HMAC of the password field. Django verifies that the
> hash in the session for each request matches the one that’s computed
> during the request. This allows a user to log out all of their
> sessions by changing their password.

So what you want to do is:

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash

class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        if user is not None:
            #wrong -> update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
        return super(UserUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: If you copied my code verbatim, I changed it to fix an issue. If you're still having issues, I would verify that the view runs the `update_session_auth_hash()` call by using `pdb`, another debugger, a print statement or raising an exception.